# How to implement socketIO in brightScript Roku

Tags: socket.io

I am Working on streaming channel for Roku platform and i am trying to fetch network packets in Roku TV. I need to implement Socket IO client implementation from the Roku TV side. Do we have any socket IO library in Roku platform, Or anything else which we can user here for implementing this feature.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

https://developer.roku.com/docs/references/brightscript/components/rostreamsocket.md

There isnt a lib i know of.